# Как передавать данные из парсера в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, multiprocessing

Пишу телеграм бота на aiogram. Основная задача - парсить почтовый ящик, брать прикрепелнные файлы из входящих писем, обрабатывать их и передавать данные из файла  в телеграм по средствам сообщений в боте. Поскольку парсер и бот работают непрерывно и паралельно, разбил сам бот и парсер на 2 процесса (вычитал что данном случе лучше чем потоки):

```
def run_bot():
    while True:
        print("Bot start")
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, loop=True)
        time.sleep(300)


def run_emailer():
    while True:
        print("Parser start")
        emailer.email_parser()
        time.sleep(180)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating processes
    p_emailer = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_bot, args=())
    p_run_bot = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_emailer, args=())

    # starting process 1
    p_emailer.start()
    # starting process 2
    p_run_bot.start()

    # wait until process 1 is finished
    p_emailer.join()
    # wait until process 2 is finished
    p_run_bot.join()
```

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не передать данные напрямую в бот из памяти, как и не вызвать какую либо функцию передачи сообщений в боте.
Сам я чайник, по этому прошу подсказать в каком направлении двигаться дальше...
Всем заранее спасибо)

Comment: Ну зачем самому так усложнять тебе жизнь. Всю логику на aiogram в основной поток, а парасер в другой поток под упраление основного потока. В вашем коде три потока

Comment: Сергей благодраю вас за пояснение. 
Опишите пожалуйста точнее что вы подразумеваете под "другой поток под упраление основного потока". Как я понимаю вызвать новый поток внутри действующего потока невозможно.  Можно только разбить основной поток на отдельные потоки.
Или вы имеете ввиду, что создается 3 потока. Один поток запускает бота, второй парсит ящик а третий, он же "основной" поток - собирает данные из парсера и передает боту?